# Python - How to calculate the elapsed time since X date?

Tags: python, elapsedtime

I have a database table with articles and each one of this articles have a submitted date. I need to calculate the days and hours since the article have been published in the database, like:

```
This article has been published 4 hours ago.
This article has been published 3 days and 4 hours ago.
```

There are already some code that I can reuse to do this? I've searched on google, but maybe I'm not using the correct words.

Any clue that could help me?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have a look at the [`datetime` package](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html), it has everything you need.

when you subtract one datetime from another, you get a `timedelta` object. You can use `total_seconds()` to get the duration in seconds and use division to convert it to hours and days. Then your only job then is to format it into a readable string.

Comment: FWIW, str() called on a datetime.timedelta object creates a string formatted like: '4 days, 23:58:57.256000'  I don't think there's a way to change the formatting, but it saves you some work if it's an acceptable format.

Comment: Excellent answer, but please note the relevant method of the timedelta class is total_seconds

Answer (score 3):

I'd convert the submitted date into a `datetime`, then use something like https://gist.github.com/207624 to convert the `datetime` to a humanized string.

Comment: Hi. You have a simple error on the 9th line of your code. It says: `dt = otherdate - now` but really should be the other way around. Maybe that was the reason for the downvoter to vote down.